# Find and remove directory from bash

Tags: bash, find

```
#!/bin/bash

# error handling
function error_handler() {
  echo "Error occurred in script at line: ${1}"
  echo "Line exited with status: ${2}"
}

trap 'error_handler ${LINENO} $?' ERR

set -o errexit
set -o errtrace

set -o nounset

# backup dir vars
BACKUPDIR=$(dirname "$0")

# check for directories
if [[ -d $BACKUPDIR/test1 ]]; then
  find $BACKUPDIR/test1 -mtime +6 -exec rm -rf {} \;
else
  :
fi
```

When I run the above test script, if the directory `test1` isn't there it runs fine. However, if the directory `test1` is there I get the following error even though it removes the directory.

```
Test ./testFind.sh  
find: ‘./test1’: No such file or directory
Error occurred in script at line: 20
Line exited with status: 1
```

How can I stop the error?

Comment: What's the purpose of the find command? Why not just `rm -rf "$BACKUPDIR"/test1` ?

Comment: In the "real", larger script I have an `-mtime +6`. I'll add it back in to help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `-prune` on the directories that you're going to delete to tell `find` not to trying to find files in them:

```
find $BACKUPDIR/test1 -mtime +6 -prune -exec rm -rf {} \;
```